# How call method from custom .net dll in vbscript

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript, com, interop

I can managed dll. This dll contains method such return custom structure.

Method and Structure

```
    [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
            private static extern uint CallNtPowerInformation(
                int InformationLevel,
                IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
                int nInputBufferSize,
                ref SystemPowerInformation spi,
                int nOutputBufferSize
            );

public SystemPowerInformation GetSystemPowerInformation()
        {
            SystemPowerInformation spi = new SystemPowerInformation();

            CallNtPowerInformation(12,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0,
                ref spi,
                Marshal.SizeOf(spi));

            return spi;
        }

[ComVisible(true)]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    [Guid("A79B0F9F-00C7-46C8-A3AE-D371E09ADB0C")]
    public struct SystemPowerInformation
    {
        public uint MaxIdlenessAllowed;
        public uint Idleness;
        public uint TimeRemaining;
        public byte CoolingMode;
    }
```

VbScript

```
set calc = CreateObject("PowerStateManagement.PowerStateManagement")

sleepTime = calc.GetLastSleepTime()
WScript.Echo(sleepTime)

wakeTime = calc.GetLastWakeTime()
WScript.Echo(wakeTime)

spi = calc.GetSystemPowerInformation()

WScript.Echo(spi.TimeRemaining)
```

I have exception when I run this script.

> 0x800a01a8 - Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'spi'

But if **GetSystemPowerInformation** method rewrite as `return spi.TimeRemaining`then this script return correct **TimeRemaining** value

Why I can't return structure, only structure's field?

Comment: Are you just missing the `set` keyword? ie `Set spi = calc.GetSystemPowerInformation()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript only supports the Variant type, and the Variant type does not support structures. After the value assignment to spi, what is the result of `VarType(spi)`? If it's a byte array you can grab the 4 bytes representing the TimeRemaining value and attempt to convert them into a uint.